# What happens with reputation from votes during suspension?

Tags: support, reputation, account-suspension

Will votes on my answers/questions cast *while* I'm suspended still increase my reputation after the suspension ends?

Comment: I would guess that if you are suspended then you have a higher chance of accumulating negative rep than positive rep while suspended. Be careful what you ask for.

Comment: Hey i don't know why i'm getting downvotes...? Is there any `Possible Duplicates`..?

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes as well.  I know that [voting works differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), but I'm not sure what the purpose of downvoting this question is.

Comment: Probably because we don't like ... the reasons why you have been on our radar, which are numerous.  Reputation you have, and none of it positive.  **Your bed, sleep in it.**

Answer (score 20):

All votes are associated to the *post* they are cast for. When your suspension period ends, your reputation will be re-calculated. This means, the votes on all of your questions and answers (positive or negative) will be counted, and the correct reputation score will be computed.

So yes, if you earn a few votes during the period, you *will* get credit for them. However, take note that if any votes were invalidated by the system, you will not receive credit for them, since they no longer exist.

If you want to try an experiment (I have no idea if this works while suspended), visit [the reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and you'll see exactly what will be counted when your reputation is re-calculated after your suspension. I think your reputation will still show as `1`, however you should be able to see the number of votes that will go into your score.